# Does GCC or Clang implement chrono::current_zone()?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, clang++

Cppreference mentions function [`current_zone()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/current_zone) as part of the timezone implementation in `<chrono>`. Has this feature been implemented in GCC or Clang? I would like to test it in one of the online tools, such as https://wandbox.org or https://godbolt.org/, but it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 5):

[Compiler support for C++20 - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20)

> | C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC libstdc++ | Clang libc++ | MSVC STL | Apple Clang |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [Calendar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Calendar) and [timezone](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Time_zone) | [P0355R7](https://wg21.link/P0355R7) | 11 (partial) | 7 (partial) | 19.29 (16.10)* | 10.0.0* |

So there is some support, but basically you have to check compilers documentation to se in details what is already implemented, or just try and see. For now using example from [docks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/current_zone) [compiles only for msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/1f9csWh4E).

Note this feature is based on [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which you can use with older version of C++ standard.

Comment: There's also [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date). I thought that's what the proposal is based on.

Answer (score 3):

There are no results in https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/search?q=current_zone (except clangd indexer) and in https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/search?q=current_zone (except for disabled chrono C++20 conformance test stuff).

> Does GCC or Clang implement chrono::current_zone()?

No, not currently.